# Determine covariance , trouble understanding standard deviation

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm supposed to determine the covariance $C(X, Y)$ when $Y∈\mathcal{N}(-6,6) , X∈\mathcal{N}(1,10)$ and correlation coefficient: $p(X,Y) = 0.1$

By using the definition of the correlation coefficient I get:

$C(X,Y) = p(X,Y) (D(X)D(Y))$

I know that D(X) is the standard deviation which is $D(X) =\sqrt{V(X)}$

But I'm having trouble understanding the standard deviation, previously I got it from calculating the variance but now I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: the question seems incomplete..

Comment: @dimebucker91 What I've written is all the information I've been given, what is missing?

Comment: @dimebucker91 it is the correlation coefficient

Comment: @dimebucker91 don't know what I'm missing then, this is just the first part of the question, no more information given

Comment: well you just added information, you initially had $X \in (0,10)$, not $X \in N(0, 10)$....

Comment: @dimebucker91 yeah sorry

Comment: @JohnDoe : Often one writes $\rho(X,Y)$ for correlation, rather than $p(X,Y). \qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite a few things for clarity:

$$
X \sim \mathcal{N}(1, 10), \quad Y \sim \mathcal{N}(-6, 6), \quad \rho_{XY} = 0.1
$$

Then:

\begin{align*}
\text{cov}(X,Y) &= \rho_{XY}\sigma_X\sigma_Y\\
& = \rho_{XY}\sqrt{V(X)}\sqrt{V(Y)}\\
& = 0.1\sqrt{10}\sqrt{6}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: This is what I thought I should do but get the wrong answer when I enter this

Comment: perhaps the gaussian is parameterised with the standard deviation rather than the variance, try: $cov(X,Y) = 0.1 \times 10 \times 6 = 6$